# How to calculate negative binomial distribution of the number of corners in a football match in python

Tags: python, scipy, prediction, statsmodels, poisson

I created an algorithm that calculates the odds for the 1x2 market of the number of corners  in football matches. I used to utilize the poisson distribution, just like this:

```
#l = mean, x = number of corners to calculate probability
def poisson(l, x):
    return (l**x)*math.exp(-l)/math.factorial(x)
```

But recently I figured out that using a negative binomial distribution could be better, considering that corners show over-dispersion (their mean is lower that their variance).

Assuming that my array of corners is [7,8,7,12,14,9,6,15,5], and I do not have other variables, how can I calculate a negative binomial distribution?

I tried like this:

```
data = [7,8,7,12,14,9,6,15,5]
dist = stats.nbinom
bounds = [(0, 30), (0, 1)]
res = stats.fit(dist, data, bounds)
print(par.params)
for x in range(0, 15):
   stats.nbinom.pmf(x, res.params.n, res.params.p)
```

But I always get in return different values (n and p) with the same data, so I tried using the statsmodels library

```
data = [7,8,7,12,14,9,6,15,5]
nb_model = sm.GLM(data, sm.families.NegativeBinomial())
nb_results = nb_model.fit()
print(nb_results.params)
```

But I get an error

```
    raise ValueError('unrecognized data structures: %s / %s' %
    ValueError: unrecognized data structures: <class 'numpy.ndarray'> / <class 
   'statsmodels.genmod.families.family.NegativeBinomial'>
```

which I guess is correlated to the fact that I do not have other variables, beside the data (the number of corners in the previous matches)

How would you calculate the negative binomial distribution based just on an array of data like this?

I appreciate any help you can provide

Answer (score 0):

You have too small amount of data in order to understand how your distribution looks like, that's why you can see different n and p every time when you run the code. As much data you have, as more likely you will see stable results for n and p.

If you want to calculate n and p anyway, you can try to solve this equation (from formulas for mean and variance of negative binomial distribution):

```
n(1-p)/p = np.mean(x)
n(1-p)/p^2 = np.var(x)
```

But I want to highlight that it's not a very good idea, I would recommend getting more data (more than 30-40 objects at least)